# Resume bash session in new TMUX or SCREEN?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, tmux

Sometimes I'll start doing something fast. I've got something to do, and I need to get it done *now*.

Then of course i realize that I need to do something else to help me finish what I started, so I want to add a new shell using tmux (or screen)... but I forgot to start tmux right off....

My question is this:

**How can I put a task to the background, start a tmux (or screen) session, and then resume my original task in tmux?**

Comment: Not a duplicate since OP already knows about `screen` and is stating that he started stuff outside of screen that he wants to import into a new (or second) screen session.

Comment: @bahamat That's the same scenario as the question I linked to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do what you want using either [`reptyr`](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) ore [`retty`](http://pasky.or.cz//dev/retty/). With either tool you can start up either `screen` or `tmux` and pull processes that have been backgrounded/disowned into either. For example:

```
$ reptyr <pid>
```

-or-

```
$ retty <pid>
```

#### References

- [Move a running process to a new screen shell](http://monkeypatch.me/blog/move-a-running-process-to-a-new-screen-shell.html)